# Is List created in top level site (parent site) visible is Child Site

Tags: list, site-collection, site

I created a custom list in a top level site of site collection, which is the parent site.
Is it possible that this list is visible in a child site?

Comment: can you speficy your questin a bit more? do you want to be able to view the list in the menu of the subsites, or do you want to make the list available through a webpart? Aside from that, you can't create lists in a site collection, but only in the sites that belong to that site collection

Comment: @Bas Lijten:Thanks for the reply..what i meant was that when we create a list in the top level site in site collection, is there some way by which we can make it visible to the child site.. say by any setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways for doing this, a simple method could be to export the listview webpart of the list from the parent site. Open the exported .webpart file and set the WebId property of the parent site since its set to 00000... Then finally import it to your subsite.

A quick search should send you in the right direction, alot of topics on this.
E.g: http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2009/01/22/a-simple-method-to-display-a-list-in-another-site/